# global cap_v4l.cpp:984 open VIDEOIO(V4L2): can't find camera device

Tags: python, opencv, flask, face-recognition, pythonanywhere

I am using OpenCV for face recognition but while uploading on server pythonanywhere I encounter the error `global cap_v4l.cpp:984 open VIDEOIO(V4L2): can't find camera device`

```
def live_face_match():
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

    while True:
        ret, frame = cap.read()
        cv2.imshow('Camera Feed', frame)

        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break

    cap.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: 1. Please always include the whole traceback/error. 2. What camera do you expect on the pythonanywhere servers?

Answer (score 0):

There is not camera device on the PythonAnywhere servers and, if there was, it would be showing you a video of the data-centre where the servers are housed.